# Error while adding a local group to local user using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I used the following command to set the password and add a group to the user :

```
$user=[ADSI]'WinNT://localhost/account5';
$user.SetPassword('Passw0rd#');
$OBjOU =[ADSI]'WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group';
$objOU.add($user.path);
```

The password is getting reset, but I am getting the following error while adding the account to the user :

> A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist.

But the local member is already present and it is resting the password of the local user.

Edited :

While trying to add a user to a group manually, the location in which the user is searched is by default a domain.The local user in the machine is not a part of this domain and so it cannot be added. When I select the location as local machine and then add the user, the user is getting added. This might be the reason for getting the above error. How can we change the location(in which to search for users) to the local machine through powershell commands?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$user=[ADSI]"WinNT://$Env:Computername/account5";
$user.SetPassword('Passw0rd#');
$OBjOU =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Env:ComputerName/Administrators,group";
$objOU.add($user.path);
```

Comment: +1 Apparently you must use the actual hostname for the user object. Neither `localhost` nor `.` will work. For the group you can use either `$env:COMPUTERNAME`, `localhost` or `.`, though. Thanks for yet another inconsistency, Microsoft.

Comment: I tried the above script on a remote machine. I am getting the following exception :

The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetPassword": "The network path was not found.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

Comment: It's not meant to be run on a remote machine. You should run it locally and I know it works, as I use it. As you were using 'localhost' before, I assume you want to run it locally anyway, right?

Comment: No. The script was being run in a remote machine. Giving localhost would run the command in the remote machine.

Comment: I have tried the same in local machine.It is giving the same error. @AdilH. : I observed something while adding user to a group using GUI. I have added it in the question

Comment: Well, I see what you are saying but no, that would not be the case because "WinNT://$Env:Computername/account5" is 'local' anyway. So, originally were saying user was not being added comment out the first two lines, does it get added? How are you running this remotely? what happens if you run it locally?

Comment: I am invoking the command remotely using the following command

'.\testgroup.ps1 -computername localhost '

I also tried the following :

 'Invoke-command -filepath C:\localgroup.ps1 -computername localhost'

But both of the commands were giving the exception : "The network path was not found."

I used the following command to run the script remotely :

'Invoke-command -filepath C:\localgroup.ps1 -computername "MachineName" -credential "MachineName\Username"'

Here also I was getting the same error.

Comment: that explains why it is not working. Please take a look at how to use invoke-command. You think you are running it against computer A, but actually you are not. So, forget about invoke-command or any other remoting stuff and just run it locally on the target machine. You will see that it will work

Comment: Invoke-command was working fine for rest of the scripts. So I don't think the issue was with the invoke-command.Even when I tried running the script locally I was getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked fine :

```
$CompStat = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem;
$Localhst = $CompStat.Name;
$Computer = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$localhst+',computer');
$accName = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+'/account8,user');
$group = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+'/testgroup,group');
$group.add($accName.path);
```